# Reference requests for an opt-cited result in Jennrich (1969)

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, reference-request

Lemma 2 on page 637 of [Jennrich (1967)](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177697731) states that:

> Let $Q$ be a real-valued function on $\Theta\times Y$ where $\Theta$
>   is a compact subset of a Euclidean space and $Y$ is a measurable
>   space. For each $\theta$ in $\Theta$ let $Q(\theta,y)$ be a measurable
>   function of $y$ and for each $y$ in $Y$ a continuous function of
>   $\theta$. Then there exists a measurable function $\hat{\theta}$ from
>   $Y$ into $\Theta$ such that for all $y$ in $Y$: $$
>  Q(\hat{\theta}(y),y)=\inf_\theta Q(\theta,y). $$

I have a few questions about this please:

- Where can I find an alternative source (preferably a text book) of proof for this result? Jennrich's writing is too dense for me at the moment. If you know a relatively accessible proof, please share it here with me and others.
- Jennrich's proof begins with:

> Let $\{\Theta_n\}$ be an increasing sequence of finite subsets of
>   $\Theta$ whose limit is dense in $\Theta$.

This seems to be a consequence of $\Theta$ being compact. What is the name of this property?

Thank you!

Comment: The property that a space contains a countable increasing sequence of finite subsets whose limit is dense should be equivalent to [separability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space). If a space is separable, which Euclidean space is, then every (topological) subspace is separable too. So compactness isn't required for that.

Comment: I just realized that I made my earlier comment in too great generality. Every subspace of a separable _metric_ space is separable, but a subspace of a separable topological space [need not be](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23493#23493). In your case this is irrelevant because you're dealing with a metric space. Just thought I'd add that though.

Answer (score 0):

A  good textbook reference for the proof and more is the section 24.1 of the following reference Statistics and Econometric Models: Volume 2, Testing, Confidence Regions, Model Selection and Asymptotic Theory by Christian Gourieroux, 
 and Alain Monfort (Translated by Quang Vuong), Cambridge University Press, 1995. Gallant and White (1988, chap. 2) is also a good reference for a slight extension of the Schmetterer-Jennrich lemma.
Fyi, the Lemma was actually first proved by Schmetterer (1965, in German). See Pötscher and Prucha (1997, Lemma 3.4) for more background info about the Schmetterer-Jennrich lemma.